# Regular expression requirements not strict enough

Tags: javascript, regex

Using regex I am attampting to limit the user's input to one of the following scenarios:

- http(s)://www.instagram.com/user
- www.instagram.com/user
- http(s)://instagram.com/user
- instagram.com/user

However, once that final case is satisfied it will accept any random string before the "instagram.com", this isn't imperitive but it's more for my own peace of mind. The regular expression I am using is the following:

```
control.value.match(/(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?instagram.com\/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/igm)
```

I would like to have it so that only one of the above cases validate. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If all the user can type is the correct URL for Instagram, why not do it for them by inserting it or creating a button

Comment: @adeneo there is more than one option available to them, the posted example is just one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the entire content matches a regular expression, there are a few ways, but my favorite is just using the regular expression itself.

You can use the line start `^` and line end `$` characters.  These are called `anchors` and you can read about them at http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Your code would look like this:

```
control.value.match(/^(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?instagram.com\/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$/igm)
```

This only works because you're looking at a single line of text.  Your `m` flag would imply multiline text (which doesn't make any sense with a url), so you should take a closer look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html.  In javascript, modifiers for the entire expression are placed as flags at the end.  You can see examples of that at http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html.

In your example, your flags are `igm` and come after the closing `/`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much man, for a moment i thought it was the javascript match() causing me the hassle. The ^ worked a charm, I also removed the m, thanks I'll go through the tutorial after as well, regex isn't my forte

Answer (score 3):

If you put ^ at the beginning of your regex it will not accept junk before. Because the ^ is the beginning of the line

Comment: And $ for the end of the line